# Is the phrase: "degenerated into subjectivity", a valid one?

Tags: expressions

I have never seen this phrase before. I can't find any search results for it on Google, I searched for: "degenerated into subjectivity", thus my question. I want to use the phrase in the following sentence: "The theory is there and the question has degenerated into subjectivity." Does this make sense?

Comment: Please pardon the poor usage of commas...

Comment: Without a complete context to show, for example, what the question was, it is impossible to be sure.  For example, if the question is about which shade of green is best to decorate the walls of a kitchen, then it - or rather, the answer to it, must be to some extent subjective (a matter of personal impressions.  If, however, the question is whether the Earth is 4,000 or 4 billion years old, one would expect this answer to be objective.  Many would say that in some quarters,  So without more information, it is impossible to tell if degenerate is appropriate.

Comment: @Tuffy, without knowing the context, we, of course, cannot know whether it is, in fact, true that something has 'degenerated into subjectivity'. What the OP probably wants to know, however, is whether the phrase is meaningful, grammatically correct, stylistically sound, not whether a particular use of it is true.

Comment: @jsw29 I see your point.  However, in that case, the question is only a matter of checking a dictionary.  I should say there needs to be more to a question than just that.

Comment: You are using *subjectivity* incorrectly. It doesn't go well with *degenerate*. It is just too endemic to take such a strong negative connotation. Perhaps it degenerated into a bunch of uninformed opinions and rants. Note *subjectivity: the quality of existing in someone's mind rather than the external world.* This would apply to most theories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**degenerate into (something)** a phrase:  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/degenerate+into+(something))

> To get worse and enter an unpleasant state.

As in:

> - Concerts always seem to degenerate into chaos once it's time to leave    the venue.
> - If you don't exercise regularly, your muscles will degenerate into mush.

Your example could be better written:

"The discussion of X has degenerated into subjectivity."

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is grammatical and uses the verb **degenerate** figuratively.

> The meeting degenerated into a free-for-all.

You're using the word **question** to mean "debate".

As for the statement making sense, it's not quite clear what you mean by "The theory is there and..."